# ObjectDataSource 's' could not find a non-generic method GetAllUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, objectdatasource

I've looked over the web and have found loads of answers none of which have helped me resolve this issue!

I have a method in a data project. I then have a project with the displaying element.

The code-behind:

```
public static DataTable GetAllobjs(SPWeb objWeb)
{
    DataTable tmpData = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.1);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.2);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.3);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.4);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.5);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.6);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.7);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.8);
        allProjects.Columns.Add(ColumnNames.9);

        //Get the raw project data 
        List<obj> data= DataAquisition.GetAllobj(objWeb);

        /// Loop through the raw data.
        foreach (obj currentInformation in data)
        {
            // Creates a new data row containing information required and adds it to the DATAtable
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        // Logs errors here
    }
    return tmpData;
}
```

In the page behind(cs) of the user control i have a Method that calls GetAllobjs(SPWeb objWeb)

```
[DataObjectMethodAttribute(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
public DataTable GetAllUsers()
{
    return Data.GetAllobjs(SPContext.Current.Web);
}
```

Then the page load:

```
ObjectDataSource d = new ObjectDataSource();
d.ID = "s";
d.SelectMethod = "GetAllUsers";
d.TypeName = SPGridView.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
this.Controls.Add(d);
/// Apply a data source to the SPGrid View
SPGridView.DataSourceID = d.ID;
```

Then on the create child control i create and bind my fields to the SPGridview and call the databind.

I thought this would work but i am getting the error. I'm not sure if i am missing some more component model [] tags somewhere i was hoping someone could possibly point out where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
d.TypeName = SPGridView.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

to:

```
 d.TypeName = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Example:
Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace Q11454649WebApp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                ObjectDataSource d = new ObjectDataSource();
                d.ID = "s";
                d.SelectMethod = "GetAllUsers";
                //d.TypeName = SPGridView.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
                d.TypeName = this.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
                this.Controls.Add(d);
                /// Apply a data source to the SPGrid View
                SPGridView.DataSourceID = d.ID;
            }
        }

        [System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
        public string[] GetAllUsers()
        {
            return new string[] { "Joe", "Alan", "Michel" };
        }
    }                              
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Q11454649WebApp._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="SPGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItem %>"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

archive project: [Q11454649WebApp.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11454649WebApp.7z)

Comment: aahhhhhgggg this works a treat but every time i sort it seems to add my user control again grrrrr